# What could parametrs of FFT function mean

Tags: c++, fft

I'm trying to understand the FFT algorithm. 
Here's a code

```
void fft(double *a, double *b, double *w, int m, int l)
{
    int i, i0, i1, i2, i3, j;
    double u, v, wi, wr;
    for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        wr = w[j << 1];
        wi = w[j << 1 + 1];
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            i0 = (i << 1) + (j * m << 1);
            i1 = i0 + (m * l << 1);
            i2 = (i << 1) + (j * m << 2);
            i3 = i2 + (m << 1);
            u = a[i0] - a[i1];
            v = a[i0 + 1] - a[i1 + 1];
            b[i2] = a[i0] + a[i1];
            b[i2 + 1] = a[i0 + 1] + a[i1 + 1];
            b[i3] = wr * u - wi * v;
            b[i3 + 1] = wr * v + wi * u;
        }
    }
}
```

If I get it right, array W is input, where every odd number is real and even is imag. A and B are imag and real parts of complex result
Also I found that l = 2**m

But when i'm trying to do this:

```
double a[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
double b[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
double w[8] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int m = 3;
int l = 8;

fft(a, b, w, m, l);
```

There's error.

Comment: Re “There's error.”: **Never** write just a sentence like that when describing software behavior. **Always** describe specifically what the computer did. For example, state the exact error message that was displayed, or show the exact output that was produced. Additionally, state what behavior was expected instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is only part of an FFT. `a` is input. `b` is output. `w` contains precomputed weights. `l` is a number of subdivisions at the current point in the FFT. `m` is the number of elements per division. The data in `a`, `b`, and `w` is interleaved complex data—each pair of `double` elements from the array consists of the real part and the imaginary part of one complex number.

The code performs one radix-two butterfly pass over the data. To use it to compute an FFT, it must be called multiple times with specific values for `l`, `m`, and the weights in `w`. Since, for each call, the input is in `a` and the output is in `b`, the caller must use at least two buffers and alternate between them for successive calls to the routine.

From the indexing performed in `i0` and `i2`, it appears the data is being rearranged slightly. This may be intended to produce the final results of the FFT in “natural” order instead of the bit-reversed order that occurs in a simple implementation.

> But when i'm trying to do this:
>
> ```
> double a[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
> double b[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
> double w[8] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
> int m = 3;
> int l = 8;
>  
> fft(a, b, w, m, l);
> ```
>
> There's error.

From `for (j = 0; j < l; j++)`, we see the maximum value of `j` in the loop is `l-1`. From `for (i = 0; i < m; i++)`, we see the maximum value of `i` is `m-1`. Then in `i0 = (i << 1) + (j * m << 1)`, we have `i0` = `((m-1) << 1) + ((l-1) * m << 1)` = `(m-1)*2 + (l-1) * m * 2` = `2*m - 2 + l*m*2 - m*2` = `2*m*l - 2`. And in `i1 = i0 + (m * l << 1)`, we have `i1` = `2*m*l - 2 + (m * l * 2)` = `4*m*l - 2`. When the code uses `a[i1 + 1]`, the index is `i1 + 1` = `4*m*l - 2 + 1` = `4*m*l - 1`.

Therefore `a` must have an element with index `4*m*l - 1`, so it must have at least `4*m*l` elements. The required size for `b` can be computed similarly and is the same.

When you call `fft` with `m` set to 3 and `l` set to 8, `a` must have 4•3•8 = 96 elements. Your sample code shows four elements. Thus, the array is overrun, and the code fails.

I do not believe it is correct that `l` should equal 2<sup>`m`</sup>. More likely, `4*m*l` should not vary between calls to `fft` in the same complete FFT computation, and, since `a` and `b` contain two `double` elements for every complex number, `4*m*l` should be twice the number of complex elements in the signal being transformed.